# Formal Power Series and 0^0

Tags: evaluation, series-expansion, calculus-and-analysis

I'm having the following problem: I define

```
series = Exp[Sum[Subscript[J, n]/n t^n, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]]
```

and it's all fine. Also when I ask Mathematica

```
D[series, t]
```

The answer is correct:

```
 E^Sum[(t^n*Subscript[J, n])/
     n, {n, 1, Infinity}]*
Sum[t^(-1 + n)*Subscript[J, 
     n], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

but when I evaluate at t=0 I have problems

```
 D[series, t]/.{t->0}
```

of course it encounters 0^0 indeterminate form because it cannot evaluate the infinite sum before.

How can I find a *clever* solution to that (without redefine Power)?

Comment: Whether the derivative is defined for `t == 0` depends on whether `Limit[D[series, t], t -> 0]` exists.

Comment: I cannot see what is your proposal. Of course the series *is* well drfined for t=0. This is because first you write t^0=1 and then you set t=0, but 1(0)=1. Here the problem is that Mathematica cannot evaluate the infinite sum (if you substitute the upper limit by 10 for example, the evaluation at t=0 yields the correct result).

Comment: I am saying that in general the derivative may or may not be defined at `t == 0` so the only way to express it without knowing more is to represent it as a `Limit`

Comment: I tried, but it cannot evaluate the limit: the output is just the input.

Comment: Without defining `Subscript[J, n]` there is no way to determine the `Limit` and know if the derivative is defined at `t == 0`. The unevaluated `Limit` accurately reflects what is known.

Comment: The J_n's are generic coefficients. Of course if I kenw the sum of the series (and its radius of convergence) the operation would be pretty easy. But mathematically the derivative of that function is a power series and by definition it is defined for the argument equals zero!